# Sphinx toctree in sidebar ONLY

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, toctree

I'm new to Sphinx and have been searching for a solution to this question for a while.

My Index Page is made from index.rst which contains a toctree. The page displays the TOC in the body as well as the sidebar. I'd like to show the TOC on the sidebar ONLY, with space to enter some text in each page body instead. In particular, the main "Welcome to My Place", currently the index.html and index.rst should be just a paragraph of blurb instead of the TOC.

I have tried this:

```
Welcome to My Place
==================

.. toctree::
   :hidden:
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:
```

But that removes the TOC from the page AND the sidebar.
How can I get that to work?

EDIT:
here's how it appears, I'd like the TOC to ONLY appear in the sidebar.
[Screen shot](https://yq6qdw.db.files.1drv.com/y4mxHNKvJrtcipHeLvj54w8EBTgXholzz__7ku1BEXZnzY2Z_j764dh1kXGBil3jo2HVy3uZQR92pnGWFz5SabOurLvhS9HEJK5q1FXj5GOJhMiXj-_FFhwsiSINjhlazzmb8xDOgbQ-NFi2yZqc5IMIivOZDFZYwF-kQOp8MfPsQsG2avieY66WBYk4sRaMZ9AJHjqJre4M2B_M_r9K3sRtg?width=842&height=782&cropmode=none)

Comment: Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
sphinx-build 1.8.3
No custom themes, so I'm assuming it's sphinxdoc

Comment: The default theme is alabaster. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/theming.html#builtin-themes

Comment: Yes, it is alabaster that I'm using.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem using Alabaster.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by including a separate file for the `toctree` and point the variable `master_doc` in conf.py to this file.

---

`conf.py`

```py
# ...
master_doc = "contents"
# ...rest of the document
```

`contents.rst`

```
.. toctree::

   example
```

`index.rst`

```
# Landing Page
 Welcome!
```